# How can I parse JSON file in Scala?

Tags: json, scala

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{"ID": "1234566", "Name": "abcd", "Hobby": "run"}
```

How can I parse that file and get the ID and Hobby?

Comment: try using Json4s - https://github.com/json4s/json4s

Comment: not really a duplicate - since the other question talk about using the built-in classes whereas this is open for using libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read json file using `sqlContext.read.json(input)` in Spark.

Sample code with `Spark version 1.6.2:`

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;  

object JsonParser {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark json extract")

             // Set this for debug mode on eclipse 
              conf.setMaster("local");

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val input = "C:\\Users\\json_extract\\test1.json"

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val df = sqlContext.read.json(input)
      df.registerTempTable("jsonExtract")

      val data = sqlContext.sql("select * from jsonExtract")
      data.show();
    sc.stop

  }
}
```

Comment: Using Spark as a Json parser is kind of heavyweight.

Comment: @Harald In case of large data set too ??